# How to parse article page links in rails with pismo and mechanic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse links on multiple-page articles to automatically click through them to extract the whole article content. I'm using mechanize, regarding to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283974/what-ruby-gem-provides-the-function-to-extract-the-content-from-web-pages) and the [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284149/66414).

How can I search for pagination links? Each articles may have different link architectures, like:

ZEITONLINE:

`<a id="hp.article.bottom.paginierung.2" class="pn-forward pn-button" title="Vor" href="http://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2013-01/Syrien-Fotografie-Reportage/seite-2">Vorwärts</a>`

ARSTECHNICA:

`<a href="http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/01/help-ive-got-windows-8-and-i-miss-my-start-menu/2"><span class="next">Next <span class="arrow">→</span></span></a>`

IGN:

`<a href="http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/01/03/the-ultimate-2013-movie-preview?page=2">Next&nbsp;»</a>`

For the IGN Link it's relatively simple to parse the link, because it contains the link text `Next`. But what about the other links? I know it should be doable, because pocket, readability and instapaper are extracting multiple page content.

Hope you can help me a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Write One Function For This

```
function proccessURL($ParentURL,$URL){
   $parse_url=parse_url($URL);
    if(@$parse_url['host']==""){
        $Parent_URL=parse_url($ParentURL);
        $path=explode("/",@$parse_url['path']);
        $redirect=0;    
        $lkey=0;
        $flag=false;
        while(list($key,$val)=each($path)){
            if($val==".." or $val=="." or $val=="..."){
                $redirect++;
                $lkey=$key;
                $flag=true;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        if($flag){
           $matches=explode("/",$Parent_URL['path']);
           end($matches);
           $b=each($matches);
           $n=$b['key'];
           $url='';
           for($i=0;$i<$n-$redirect;$i++){
               $url.=$matches[$i]."/";
           }   
           for($i=$redirect+1;next($path);$i++){
               $url.=$path[$i]."/";
           }
           rtrim($url,"/");
           $parse_url['path']=$url;
        }else{
            $parse_url['path']="/".@$parse_url['path'];
        }
    }else{
        $Parent_URL['scheme']=$parse_url['scheme'];
        $Parent_URL['host']=$parse_url['host'];
    }
    //print_r($parse_url);
    if(@$parse_url['query']!=""){
        $parse_url['query']="?".@$parse_url['query'];
    }
    if(@$parse_url['fragment']!=""){
        $parse_url['fragment']="#".@$parse_url['fragment'];
    }
    return $Parent_URL['scheme']."://".@$Parent_URL['host'].@$parse_url['path'].@$parse_url['query'].@$parse_url['fragment'];
}
```

This Function solve link Address

sample:

```
$CorrectLink=proccessURL("http://www.sepidarcms.ir/kernel/","../plugin/1.php");
```

The Output is "http://www.sepidarcms.ir/plugin/1.php"
Now You Can Parse Url By preg_match_all

```
$html="Your HTML Str";
$URL="Your HTML Page Link";
preg_match_all("/href=\"([^\"]*)\"/is", $html, $matches);
while(list($key,$val)=each($matches[1])){
$val=proccessURL($URL,$val);
    echo $val;
}
```

This code List All href Url For You Correctly